# Derivative of sin(x) and cos(x) by definition of derivative and Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

How to use the below to find the derivative of sin(x) (and cosine, too)?

$$\sin(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\ , \ x\in \mathbb{R}$$

$$\cos(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\ , \ x\in \mathbb{R}$$

$$\lim_{h\to\infty}\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}$$

Thanks!